# Determine max length of thrust::device_vector

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Is there a way to determine the maximum size of `thrust::device_vector<T>` that you can safely allocate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward way that I am aware of. My usual approach has been to do something like this:

```
const size_t MB = 1<<20;

size_t reserved, total;
cudaMemGetInfo( &reserved, &total );
char fail = 0;
while( cudaMalloc( (void**)&pool, reserved ) != cudaSuccess )
{
    reserved -= MB;
    if( reserved < MB )
    {
        fail = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

which starts with the total free memory returned from `cudaMemGetInfo`, then decrements it my a "reasonable" size (as best as I could tell in the GT200 era, the GPU MMU has a couple of different page sizes, with 1Mb being the largest). The loop continues until you either get an allocation, or memory is so fragmented or exhausted that even a single page will fail. Not very pretty, but it seems to work 99.999% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

use `cudaMemGetInfo`.

[docs here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74.html#gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74)

Comment: Due to memory fragmentation the amount of free memory reported by `cudaMemGetInfo` wont usually be in a continuous block. Is there a way to ask for the largest continuous block without resorting to binary search between zero and total free memory?

Comment: @Craz hmm, not sure.  check through driver api.  might be smth there

Comment: @Craz: not really. I usually start with the result of `cudaMemGetInfo` and then decrement by a reasonable unit (I usually use a Mb), until it succeeds. You can see an example of this in this [code snippet](https://github.com/avidday/hpl-cuda/blob/master/src/auxil/HPL_gpusupport.c#L96-107) if you are interested.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks, I though that might be the case. If you'd like to repost that as an answer (or add it to this one) I'll mark it accepted.