# Why is the iterating range of thrust::reduce limited to 2048 doubles in device code?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am using the NVIDIA HPC SDK (2022) to compile the following code, the basic purpose of which is to sum a `N`x`M` matrix into a vector of size `N`.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>

constexpr unsigned int N = 2048, M = 2048;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    thrust::device_vector<double> g_vec1(N*M);
    thrust::device_vector<double> g_vec2(N);
    thrust::fill(thrust::device, g_vec1.begin(),g_vec1.end(),1.);

    
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::
            device_vector<double>::iterator> g_it_vec(N);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        g_it_vec[i] = g_vec1.begin() + i*M;

            
    thrust::transform(g_it_vec.begin(),g_it_vec.end(),g_vec2.begin(),
        [](const auto& it) {
            return thrust::reduce(thrust::device,
                it, it+M,0.);});

}
```

When I run this code on a Geforce RTX 3080Ti, an error occurs for M > 2048 doubles (or M > 1024 when I use complex doubles):

```
temporary_buffer::allocate: get_temporary_buffer failed
…
temporary_buffer::allocate: get_temporary_buffer failed
terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘thrust::system::system_error’
what(): transform: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorLaunchFailure: unspecified launch failure
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How did this happen? Is it related to the 1024 maximum thread number of a block?

Or is there any standard means to reduce a matrix (2d array) along the inner dimension?

Comment: Maybe you reached the max size you can allocate with `device_vector`? You might refer this to check the max size you are allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542342/determine-max-length-of-thrustdevice-vector

Comment: What is your compilation command?

Comment: nvc++ -stdpar main.cpp

Comment: @Ranoiaetep
if I put a std::cout <<"aa" << std::endl just before the thrust::tranform, the "aa" always show up even if the error occur, so I think N*M vector is successfully built

Comment: Maybe this one can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64441827/cuda-thrustsort-met-memory-problem-when-i-still-have-enough-memory

Comment: If you are using `-stdpar` to get `nvc++` to include the Thrust headers that is probably a bad idea as it will also transform all heap memory to CUDA managed memory (needed when offloading C++17 parallel algorithms to the GPU). Instead use `-I/path/to/thrust/headers` like you would do with `g++` when not using the device backend. The NVHPC SDK actually ships with multiple locations of Thrust headers, one with the `nvc++` compiler and one with each version of the CUDA toolkit. For using Thrust directly would try to use a Toolkit version of Thrust or a newer one from Github.

Comment: @paleonix I take your advise and compile the code with "  nvc++ -I/lustre/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/2022/cuda/include/  main.cpp", but the compilation failed with error: static assertion failed with "unimplemented for this system"..., is there anything else i miss?

Comment: You have to make it a .cu file when using CUDA as backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Context

`thrust::reduce` uses [`cub::DeviceReduce`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html) in the backend. The documentation says that

> DeviceReduce methods can be called within kernel code on devices in which CUDA dynamic parallelism is supported.

When Thrust allocates scratch space for `DeviceReduce` with `cudaMalloc` in device code, it probably runs into [size limitations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-allocation-and-lifetime):

> `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaFree()` have distinct semantics between the host and device environments. [...] When invoked from the device runtime these functions map to device-side `malloc()` and `free()`. This implies that within the device environment the total allocatable memory is limited to the device `malloc()` heap size, which may be smaller than the available unused device memory.

##### Solution Candidate 1: Increase `cudaLimitMallocHeapSize`

This limit can be set with [`cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, value)`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g05956f16eaa47ef3a4efee84563ccb7d) which should enable bigger reductions.

##### Solution Candidate 2: Use Custom Allocators (untested)

When calling Thrust algorithms on the host, one can avoid temporary allocations for scratch space by passing a custom allocator to the execution policy as demonstrated in [`examples/cuda/custom_temporary_allocation.cu`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/6f64b4a86b0ba1f4e8f3da6c4f7cddc2c91e08f4/examples/cuda/custom_temporary_allocation.cu). I have never tried to do this in device code so I can't guarantee that this is implemented, but one could try to do the allocations on the host, wrap them in an allocator on the device and pass them to `thrust::device`. If this works, doing a single big allocation on the host should be much more efficient than doing many (`N`) small allocations on the device.

##### Solution Candidate 3: Avoid Using CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (preferred)

You can find multiple alternative ways of implementing this reduction in my answers to [How to do a reduction over one dimension of 2D data in Thrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263160/how-to-do-a-reduction-over-one-dimension-of-2d-data-in-thrust) and [Parallelization of a for loop consisting of Thrust Transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017622/parallelization-of-a-for-loop-consisting-of-thrust-transforms/75019751#75019751). In short I would recommend using [`cub::DeviceSegmentedReduce`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_segmented_reduce.html) (from the host).

---

I prefer avoiding CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (CDP) for this problem not only because it is deprecated* in Thrust >= 1.15, but also because I do not expect it to give good performance for problems which do not **need** CDP due to the amount of parallelism being data dependent**. The very regular problem of reducing a dimension of a dense matrix **does not need Dynamic Parallelism** and therefore performance should not have to suffer from CDP overheads.

---

*: [CUDA 12 introduced a new CDP API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cdp2-vs-cdp1) disallowing `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in device code which Thrust needs to keep usage consistent between host and device. The Thrust CDP [deprecation notice](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/releases/tag/1.15.0) says

> **A future version of Thrust will remove support for CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (CDP).** This will only affect calls to Thrust algorithms made from CUDA device-side code that currently launches a kernel; such calls will instead execute sequentially on the calling GPU thread instead of launching a device-wide kernel.

I.e. `thrust::device` will just become the same as `thrust::seq` when used in device code. This would probably solve the issue in terms of a sequential reduction not needing the additional scratch space, but performance would be bad to to the reduced amount of parallelism.

---

**: I.e. the ideal number of threads not being known at kernel launch on the host.